# How to add input language from terminal

Tags: command-line, language-support, input-language

I sometimes use input languages / keyboard layouts, which I don't want to have constantly in list of languages. For example, at some time I might want to regularly switch between English and French. At another time I switch only between English and German. Right now I am manually adding and removing the input sources through Ubuntu's settings menu (Region & Language). Is it possible to edit the list of available input languages through the command line, so that the process can be automated?

Comment: Sure, go ahead! But what's your question?

Comment: I dont know how it can be done, obviosly

Comment: You need to be more specific. What exactly do you want to achieve and what have you tried so far? Questions amounting to "please write some code for me" are usually considered to broad on AskUbuntu unless they cover a sufficiently narrow use case.

Comment: No, i don`t need to be more specific. I described what i want to achieve. Tried google it and found nothing. i wanted an answer, and i got it.

Comment: You were lucky that somebody had the right hunch of what you wanted specifically because I didn't even though I could have given you the same answer with that knowledge.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The terminal commands below are probably useful in such a script.

See the current list of input sources:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources
```

Example command to set a new list of input sources:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources "[('xkb', 'us'), ('xkb', 'se')]"
```

Comment: You saved me. Thank you.